# Подсчитать расстояние LineString в MySql

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, имеется LineString для которого надо рассчитать длину. Пытался сделать так,

```
SELECT ST_Length(AsText(`coordinates`)) FROM cabledata limit 5;
```

но на выходе всегда получаю null. Есть ли вообще возможность посчитать длину в MySql?

Желаемый результат:

| meters |
| --- |
| 2500 |
| 750 |
| 2364 |

Comment: Выложите пример данных (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 записей) и требуемый результат запроса.

Comment: Пример расчёта длины LINESTRING : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ae6e0e1e7366eecee6232dabbe9fb4c

Comment: @Akina http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09916e/1 . Обновил вопрос, где указал какой бы хотел видеть ответ

Comment: @Akina вроде то что нужно, но в какой единицы измерения это? Хотелось бы метры

Comment: SRID=0 не позволяет использовать единицы длины.

Comment: @Akina понял, спасибо

Comment: См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a65c16c260064f74c0b03933014da12). Поменял SRID, поставил считать в метрах - по карте вроде похоже на правду.

Comment: @Akina оформите это как ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы я отметил решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример расчёта длины LINESTRING:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (line GEOMETRY);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES 
> (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (1 1, 2 2, 3 1, 4 2)'));
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ST_AsText(line), ST_Length(line) FROM test;
> ```
>
> | ST_AsText(line) | ST_Length(line) |
> | --- | --- |
> | LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 1,4 2) | 4.242640687119286 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ae6e0e1e7366eecee6232dabbe9fb4c)*

---

Расчёт на предоставленных данных (SRID изменён с 0 на 4326), в метрах.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a65c16c260064f74c0b03933014da12

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cabledata` (
>   `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `coordinates` linestring NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO `cabledata` set coordinates = ST_GeomFromText("LINESTRING(57.223896543525 60.08284845505477,57.224666502604 60.08295820801504,57.225172514244 60.083046018147,57.225704981303 60.08310879476994,57.226027409155 60.0832051653,57.226187441077 60.083256293377985)",4326);
> INSERT INTO `cabledata` set coordinates = ST_GeomFromText("LINESTRING(57.230589493775 60.08595911328098,57.231265870806 60.08602692418094,57.2315360436 60.08612390578401,57.23189156935 60.086119848024964,57.232287739405 60.08614797677296)",4326);
> INSERT INTO `cabledata` set coordinates = ST_GeomFromText("LINESTRING(57.237716659958 60.086963747497975,57.23796277784 60.08699119328696,57.23865898327 60.08710815884797,57.238934277198 60.08714999292306)",4326);
> INSERT INTO `cabledata` set coordinates = ST_GeomFromText("LINESTRING(58.267664587347 57.820157781244,58.267666527077 57.819787636399,58.267708848424 57.81961530447,58.267707085035 57.81907081604)",4326);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, ST_Length(coordinates, 'metre') FROM cabledata;
> ```
>
> | id | ST_Length(coordinates, 'metre') |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 256.4856608555175 |
> | 2 | 189.83422511452227 |
> | 3 | 136.07477319241113 |
> | 4 | 64.84093932155407 |